# open a .json file with multiple dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a problem that I can't solve with python, it is probably very stupid but I didn't manage to find the solution by myself.

I have a .json file where the results of a simulation are stored. The result is stored as a series of dictionaries like

```
{"F_t_in_max": 709.1800264942982, "F_t_out_max": 3333.1574129603068, "P_elec_max": 0.87088836042046958, "beta_max": 0.38091242406098391, "r0_max": 187.55175182942901, "r1_max": 1354.8636763521174, " speed ": 8}
{"F_t_in_max": 525.61428305710433, "F_t_out_max": 2965.0538075438467, "P_elec_max": 0.80977406754203796, "beta_max": 0.59471606595464666, "r0_max": 241.25371753877008, "r1_max": 688.61786996066826, " speed ": 9}
{"F_t_in_max": 453.71124051199763, "F_t_out_max": 2630.1763649193008, "P_elec_max": 0.64268078173342935, "beta_max": 1.0352896471221695, "r0_max": 249.32706230502498, "r1_max": 709.11415981343885, " speed ": 10}
```

I would like to open the file and and access the values like to plot "r0_max" as function of "speed" but I can't open unless there is only one dictionary.
I use

```
with open('./results/rigid_wing_opt.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

but When the file contains more than one dictionary I get the error

ValueError: Extra data: line 5 column 1 - line 6 column 1 (char 217 - 431)

Comment: Read the file line-by-line and parse each line as JSON.

Answer (score 11):

If your input data is exactly as provided then you should be able to interpret each individual dictionary using `json.load`. If each dictionary is on its own line then this should be sufficient:

```
with open('filename', 'r') as handle:
    json_data = [json.loads(line) for line in handle]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend reading the file line-by-line and convert each line independently to a dictionary.

You can place each line into a list with the following code:

```
import ast
# Read all lines into a list
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# Convert each list item to a dict
content = [ ast.literal_eval( line ) for line in content ]
```

Or an even shorter version performing the list comprehension on the same line:

```
import ast
# Read all lines into a list
with open(fname) as f:
    content = [ ast.literal_eval( l ) for l in f.readlines() ]
```

Comment: If changing the input file format was an option, I would suggest make it a proper JSON array of objects instead.

Comment: You can do the list comprehension on the filehandle

Comment: @MatthewFranglen - Yep, I've added that as an additional version... I like to place as many comments into the code I post on [so] - sometimes that negates the whole pythonic mindset - but I feel it's better for cases where you're explaining as opposed to writing production code.

Comment: @Lix np :) You can just use the plain filehandle in the list comprehension and it will behave as if you called readlines().

Comment: @MatthewFranglen - I don't think I follow what you're saying.. Care to make an edit to my answer?

Answer (score 3):

`{...} {...}` is not proper json.  It is two json objects separated by a space.  Unless you can change the format of the input file to correct this, I'd suggest you try something a little different.  If the data is a simple as in your example, then you could do something like this:

```
with open('filename', 'r') as handle:
    text_data = handle.read()
    text_data = '[' + re.sub(r'\}\s\{', '},{', text_data) + ']'
    json_data = json.loads(text_data)
```

This should work even if your dictionaries are not on separate lines.

Answer (score -2):

That is not valid JSON. You can't have multiple obje at the top level, without surrounding them by a list and inserting commas between them.

Comment: It's a valid JSON stream format.